# cp -r painfully slow on OSX when copying git repo

Tags: git, macos, cp

I'm trying to copy a git repo `~/work/repo` to `~/work/repo1` with `cp -r repo repo1` however it's unusably slow.

I'm running osx 10.12.5 and using fish shell (though I doubt that matters).

The repo is rather large, around 800mb. Why was it faster to clone the repo than copy it with `cp`?

Comment: Probably not relevant to your issue, but, as per the man page, you should not use `-r`. Use `-R`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this could be caused by the 'cp' which do not creates hard-links when copying files. Instead of hard-link whole content of file needs to be read and written to the disk again. Also the slow-down is increased when these operations are done on the same HDD.

'[man cp](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html)' suggests to use the 'pax' utility which creates just hard-links instead of copying whole content of file. See '[man pax](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pax.1.html)' for more details.

```
       $ mkdir newdir
       $ cd olddir
       $ pax -rw . ../newdir
```

Comment: Hm. You're saying that `cp` copies the entire file over while pax simply links it? If I were to delete `repo` what would happen to its copy, `repo1`? More importantly, if I changed branches in `repo` would `repo1` reflect those changes if I were to use pax?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have pax:

```
mkdir repo1
cd repo
tar cf - . | (cd ../repo1 ; tar xf -)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using APFS, it supports cloning files. That's similar to hard links but with copy-on-write semantics. No data is copied until is has to be, so it's very fast. So, do `cp -ac repo repo1`.